# How do i get data from mysql database into flash?

Tags: flash

I am reading one tutorial :-

http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Integrating-Flash-and-mySQL/2334

But i can't understand what is "Gateway.php" and all such things . Can anybody point me to some nice tutorial link? I am a beginner in Flash.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, since flash runs in the user's browser, you do not connect directly to a database from flash. Instead your flash application contacts a server endpoint (written in a server side scripting language, such as php) which fetches the data from the database and serves it to your flash application.
Check out this video tutorial. It might help you: http://library.creativecow.net/articles/brimelow_lee/php_mysql/video-tutorial

Answer (score 3):

Check this short video out for a brief overview: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRi-oxjFfCU
In order to do anything of the sorts you should at least have some basic PHP, MySQL and ActionScript skills.

Google: Flash+MySQL it isn't hard. If you have specific questions please ask.

(P.S. Sorry for leaving a reply, my reputation does not allow me to comment yet.)